# Upload multiple image file using HttpURLConnection

Tags: php, android

I want to upload mutliple image file using HttpURLConnection, and number of image is not fixed to how many file to upload from android.

Please dont send the link of MultiPartEntity.I just want this done using HttpURLConnection and don't want to use any other external library for upload file.

I want to upload file using HTTPUrlConnection for example please refer this link

http://www.17od.com/2010/02/18/multipart-form-upload-on-android/

this is for single file upload code i want to upload multiple

And please the example of php script.

Comment: Try this http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically using HttpURLConnection.

Comment: But what is PHP side implemention.

Comment: Please refer this for php side http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686806/httpurlconnection-to-send-image-audio-and-video-files-with-parameter-may-stri OR http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/file-upload-on-php-server-in-android.html OR http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/26/upload-image-android-device-server-method-4/

Comment: This all link are single file upload at server side.I will send multiple image file to server at a time so how can i save to server.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069837/php-get-names-of-multiple-uploaded-files

Comment: Sorry, i try it but not working

Comment: I found the solution and thnx for help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes finally i got answer.

At android side.

> Fileuploader.java

```
public class FileUploader {
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;

    public FileUploader(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
                true);
    }

    /**
     * Adds a form field to the request
     * @param name field name
     * @param value field value
     */
    public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
                LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     * @param fieldName name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
     * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
            throws IOException {
        String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
        writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                        + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(
                "Content-Type: "
                        + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
                .append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead = -1;
        while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        inputStream.close();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     * @param name - name of the header field
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }

    /**
     * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
     * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
     * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

> On mainactivity file

On the mainactivity.java just call this function and imgPaths is array of images path.

```
 public void uploadFile(ArrayList<String> imgPaths) {

        String charset = "UTF-8";
        //File uploadFile1 = new File("e:/Test/PIC1.JPG");
        //File uploadFile2 = new File("e:/Test/PIC2.JPG");

        File sourceFile[] = new File[imgPaths.size()];
        for (int i=0;i<imgPaths.size();i++){
            sourceFile[i] = new File(imgPaths.get(i));
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),imgPaths.get(i),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        String requestURL = "your API";

        try {
            FileUploader multipart = new FileUploader(requestURL, charset);

            multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "CodeJava");
            multipart.addHeaderField("Test-Header", "Header-Value");

            multipart.addFormField("description", "Cool Pictures");
            multipart.addFormField("keywords", "Java,upload,Spring");

            for (int i=0;i<imgPaths.size();i++){
                multipart.addFilePart("uploaded_file[]", sourceFile[i]);
            }

            /*multipart.addFilePart("fileUpload", uploadFile1);
            multipart.addFilePart("fileUpload", uploadFile2);*/

            List<String> response = multipart.finish();

            System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED:");

            for (String line : response) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

> uploader.php

```
foreach ($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"][$key];
    $file_path = "../post_uploaded_images/";
        $file_path = $file_path . $name;
            if(@move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $file_path)) 
            {
               echo "success";

            } else{

                echo "fail";
            }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Dot net api for upload the image and field but i am getting this type of error {"Message":"Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details."}

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR THIS ANSWER! I've been looking for this answer for about 3 weeks now! IT WORKED! :)

Comment: @akhil batlawala what if i want to send a string with the images please let me know what all changes i need to make

Comment: Add your string in addFormField()
multipart.addFormField("keywords", "your string");
multipart.addFilePart("uploaded_file", "file path");

Comment: Can you explain to me why the filepart has a filename field? what use is it for the server side?

Comment: filename is use to set the file name and at the serverside you can access this name via $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"][$key].

Comment: @akhilbatlawala can you edit code for providing progress that I can show through ProgressDialog or replace it well managed by AsyncTask?