# Upload pdf file to server and get its url

Tags: php, android, pdf, upload, multipart

I want user to upload pdf to server and make it downloadable to other user.I want to save the url of uploaded file to databse and then pickup that url to display the other user. I am learning android ,  so i dont have much idea . 
here is my code , i had tried to do it using multipart:-

```
public class Upload extends Activity {
String path=null;
private String getpath(String path){
    return path;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.upload);
Button browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse);
Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
browse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"), 1);


    }

});

upload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        upload up = new upload(); 
        up.execute();

    }
});

}
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        Uri data = result.getData();
         String pathe = data.getPath();
         path = getpath(pathe);
         Toast.makeText(Upload.this, path, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
}




private class upload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
pd= ProgressDialog.show(Upload.this, "Uploading", "Please Wait");
super.onPreExecute();
}
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    pd.dismiss();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Toast.makeText(Upload.this, path,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    String url = "http://192.168.43.50/projectpri/upload.php";
    File file = new File(path);
    file.getAbsolutePath();
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION,HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        MultipartEntity mpe = new MultipartEntity();
        ContentBody cbfile =new FileBody(file);
        mpe.addPart("file", cbfile);
        httppost.setEntity(mpe);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity();
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // show error
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full working example, tested for files over 100 Mb, replace `your_package` with your package name.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="your_package" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Layout activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Browse"
        android:id="@+id/browse"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Upload"
        android:id="@+id/upload"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity MainActivity**

```
package your_package;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Uri path;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browse);
        Button upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);

        browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("application/pdf");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select PDF"), 1);
            }
        });
        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                (new Upload(MainActivity.this, path)).execute();

            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent result) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                path = result.getData();
            }
        }
    }
}

class Upload extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    private Context c;
    private Uri path;

    public Upload(Context c, Uri path) {
        this.c = c;
        this.path = path;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(c, "Uploading", "Please Wait");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pd.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String url_path = "http://192.168.43.50/projectpri/upload.php";
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        int maxBufferSize = 1024;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url_path);
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

            OutputStream outputStream = conn.getOutputStream();
            InputStream inputStream = c.getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);

            int bytesAvailable = inputStream.available();
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            inputStream.close();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conn.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.i("result", line);
            }
            reader.close();
            conn.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Server side PHP**

```
$file_name = date("U").".pdf"; //name of your file
$server_path = "/path/to/file/folder/"; //server path to folder
$web_path = "http://192.168.43.50/projectpri/file/"; //web path to folder

$file = $server_path.$file_name;
file_put_contents($file,"");

$fp = fopen("php://input", 'r');
while ($buffer =  fread($fp, 8192)) {
    file_put_contents($file,$buffer,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

echo $web_path.$file_name;
```

Comment: i have to add uri instead of "yourfile" ?

Comment: @MayankKhursija if you have full path, you can use your way: File file = new File(path);

Comment: Actually i dont know its full path of uri in my code @Sam

Comment: @MayankKhursija Have you tried dumping both $_FILES and $_POST variables on your server side? Your server side receive something?

Comment: check the answer and directions below

Comment: @SamIvichuk i am working on php on server side. Nope i Just used $_FILES , Anyway tell me the right php which should be used?

Comment: @MayankKhursija I'm very sorry, my previous answer was incorrect, I've updated my answer with the working code

Comment: I am running my project on Localhost , Xampp . So , in my htdocs folder there is folder name projectpri in which i have created a folder name file according to web path given in PHP . what will be my server path ? @SamIvichuk

Comment: @MayankKhursija You can use `__DIR__."/file/"`. `__DIR__` - is the path to your current script (I assume that your upload.php and file folder locate together)

Comment: how to give params.??

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you shouldn't use HttpClient, MultipartEntitiy because they are **deprecated** and not used at all and **not recommended** by http://developer.android.com/.

- I have also used your these classes, but it's time to upgrade to the market and updates with the current android M.
- I also know that maximum tutorials on internet are related to HttpClient etc. which are not useful for current time go for **HttpUrlConnection**.

*For you convenience check the following links:*

**General knowledge:**

[Android deprecated apache module (HttpClient, HttpResponse, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29294479/android-deprecated-apache-module-httpclient-httpresponse-etc)

http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html

**For post to server helpful links for you:**

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically

[Upload multiple image file using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984323/upload-multiple-image-file-using-httpurlconnection)

http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/upload-files-by-sending-multipart-request-programmatically

> For posting data to server you can also use library with less effort
>   like volley, Retrofit. etc.

You have to do some experiment on it which will safe future of your code around various android versions and in effective manner.

Thanks