# File Upload error from android to server

Tags: android, multipartform-data, android-file, android-restrictions

Any one help me , if i upload zip file from android to server throw error in server

```
org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly
```

I follow bellow `URL`

[Upload multiple image file using HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984323/upload-multiple-image-file-using-httpurlconnection)

always return failure from server. Any one can help me?

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you