# Send Multiple Images to server along with a tag in android

Tags: php, android

I am able to send multiple images on the server by using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984323/upload-multiple-image-file-using-httpurlconnection), but I also need to send a tag with those multiple images. Can you suggest what changes I need to do in my php script and my java code that are in that link?

Comment: tag is basically a string

Comment: you can use a multipart request, try using retrofit library, remember that large data transfer is not recommend with multipart.

Comment: @SarthakMittal its just a small string but i need to send it with the images array

Comment: i m talking about image data

Answer (score 1):

Add this library.

```
     compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.6'
     compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.3'
```

And than

```
  private void sendImage(final String fileString, String fileMessageId)

 {
  Bitmap bitmap;
  DataOutputStream dos = null;


String sResponse = null;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileString);

File sourceFile = new File(fileString);


String upLoadServerUri = WSConfig.UPLOAD_FILE_URL;
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(upLoadServerUri);


try {


    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    entity.addPart("files",
            new FileBody(sourceFile));
    entity.addPart("tag",
                new StringBody("any tag here"));

    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    HttpResponse response;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        sResponse = reader.readLine();




    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

You can send multiple image file and add it in     entity.addPart("files",
                new FileBody(sourceFile)); 
and multiple tags too using StringBody

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Thank you very much though it was not the answer that i expected but your one line entity.addPart("tag",new StringBody("any tag here")); gave me a great hint and i was able to complete my task

Comment: Sorry but this was not the answer as i said above as according to my question i want the change in the code at that link

Answer (score 0):

I just have to do multipart.addFormField("tag","Your String");